Solaris 10 g++ virtual memory exhausted
I am trying to use the cm3-unix64le-d5.11.1-20210610 from the Modula 3 github. i am running the .cpp file and I get a virtual memory exhausted: Not enough space error. I have 16GB of RAM and I'm running Solaris 10 u11 on an amd64 cpu. My swap partition has 2097144 free, out of 2097144. I'm using gcc5g++ from opencsw. the c++ file is only about 300 mb.
Here is the terminal output. the warnings don't seem to be problematic.
# g++ -g -pthread -c /Desktop/cm3-boot-unix64le-d5.11.1-20210610.cpp 
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER ArrayType__InitCoster(ArrayType__P, BOOLEAN)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.m3:429:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.i3:134:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.m3:433:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.i3:134:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.m3:434:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/types/ArrayType.i3:134:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/float/IEEE/LongFloat.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER LongFloat__ILogb(LongFloat__T)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/float/IEEE/LongFloat.m3:53:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/float/Common/Float.ig:257:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/float/IEEE/LongFloat.m3:55:38:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/MasmObjFile.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER MasmObjFile__NextSymOffset(MasmObjFile__DState*, MasmObjFile__SKind)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/MasmObjFile.m3:750:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/MasmObjFile.i3:92:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/MasmObjFile.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER MasmObjFile__NextRelocOffset(MasmObjFile__DState*, MasmObjFile__SKind)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/MasmObjFile.m3:762:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/MasmObjFile.i3:92:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/types/OpenArrayType.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER OpenArrayType__InitCoster(OpenArrayType__P, BOOLEAN)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/types/OpenArrayType.m3:282:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/types/OpenArrayType.i3:122:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/float/IEEE/RealFloat.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER RealFloat__ILogb(RealFloat__T)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/float/IEEE/RealFloat.m3:49:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/float/Common/Float.ig:257:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/float/IEEE/RealFloat.m3:51:38:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/types/RecordType.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER RecordType__InitCoster(RecordType__P, BOOLEAN)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/types/RecordType.m3:390:16:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
[01m[K../src/types/RecordType.i3:99:20:[m[K [01;36m[Knote: [m[Kin definition of macro '[01m[KINT64_[m[K'
[01m[K../src/misc/Scanner.m3:[m[K In function '[01m[KINTEGER Scanner__HexDigitValue(m3_CHAR)[m[K':
[01m[K../src/misc/Scanner.m3:509:38:[m[K [01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Koverflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
virtual memory exhausted: Not enough space


hi! welcome here! One nitpick: you're not running it, you're compiling it; that's something different!

hm, gcc5 is really rather old, but Solaris 10 is positively ancient, so it might be the most modern you get for that? Don't know. It might just be that CM3 triggers a bug in an older compiler they no longer support. My best approach here would be to use a more modern C++ compiler; probably modern GCC can be compiled on/for Solaris 10, still.

I will try installing a new gcc, though unfortunately, I will have to do a gcc from source as I can't find any newer precompiled gcc packages. Solaris 10 doesn't come with gcc, I had to install a package for it. Solaris 10 comes with cc and CC by default though.

I mean, it's good that you figured out how to build on Solaris-amd64 at all – it's not listed as supported platform for CM3 anywhere.

if you go to m3-sys/cminstall/src/config in the current version of the CM3 github, it is one of the supported configs, but when I try running the concierge.py I had to remove a bunch of f from various strings for it it even run, then it just gives an error message as if I  hadn't specified any commands when running it. though it could just be that python 3.3 is too old for the script. also CM3 says it supports little endian unixes

the required Python and compiler versions should be documented somewhere, else that would be something that you would want to help the project documenting, for example by making a bug report that this doesn't work on Solaris 10 amd64, and then later actually adding a document somewhere in the source tree that specifies what you figure out. For an old compiler running on wildly different platforms, this is really all horrifically underdocumented, and quite frankly, slightly disorganized.
